# Passing a date -d to sed command

Tags: date, sed, date-conversion

I got a script looking like that :

```
function tvpsport(){
wget -qO- 'https://sport.tvp.pl/'|
     grep -i -B 9 'video_id'|
     grep 'title\|broadcast_start\|video'|
     sed -e 's/"//g' \
         -e 's/,$//g' \
         -e 's/\\u2013/-/g' \
         -e 's/\\u0105/ą/g' \
         -e 's/\\u0119/ę/g' \
         -e 's/\\u0142/ł/g' \
         -e 's/\\u00f3/ó/g' \
         -e 's/\\u015a/Ś/g' \
         -e 's/\\u017a/ź/g' \
         -e 's/\\u017c/ż/g' \
         -e 's/\\u0144/ń/g' \
         -e 's/title : //g' \
         -e "s/broadcast_start : /$(date -d) /g" \
         -e 's/video_id : /https:\/\/tvp.pl\/sess\/TVPlayer2\/embed.php?ID=/g'
}
```

which gives output :

Title of transmission
date -d {time format}
a link to transmission

I want to express that format date to human readable (from eg. 161145246842 to dd/mm/YYYY)
and output like :

date (dd/mm/YYYY) title of transmission
a link to a transmission

I tried to covrt date on this line :

-e 's/broadcast_start : /date -d /g' \

but with no luck

Comment: `sed` does not portably have any feature like this, but GNU `sed` has an `/e` flag for executing commands. If you need a portable solution, maybe switch to Awk (or Perl, though it's not standard).

Comment: Another possibility is storing the date string in `$date` and making that `-e "s/broadcast_start : /$date/g" `

Comment: You could do all of the greps+sed+date internally with GNU awk. Post a [mcve] with concise, testable sample input and expected output and tag your question with awk if you'd like help with that.

Comment: You could remove your line ` -e "s/broadcast_start : /$(date -d) /g" ` and add, after the `sed` command, this awk call `| awk '/"broadcast_start" : / {ts=$0; gsub(/^.* : /, "", ts); gsub("," ,"", ts); date=strftime("%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S", ts/10000); gsub(/[0-9]+,/, ""); print $0 date ","; next} {print}' `

Comment: After I did that the output for the broadcast thing is : broadcast_start : (unix time) but what I want is ti normaltime. Unfortunetuly I barely know awk so I can't really understand this.